# Set multiple domain for one language

Tags: 6

I am running a d6 website with i18n and I have multiple domain on it working very fine. Now I want to add another domain but for an existing language so what is the best solution for that.

In fact, this additionnal domain is for the mobile version of the website and because menus depends on language domain selection, I cant' get my menus using the mobile domain but the default domain, that's why I want to add another language but I can't :)

Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite second language domain to the "primary" one in settings.php
Something like

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'newlang.example.com') {
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'lang.example.com';
}
```

Comment: This advice saved me! Not sure why someone voted it down (wish people would elaborate when they do that).

Comment: OK - now I think I understand why this solution was voted down: it did solve a lot of problems, but it created a worse one: the newlang.example.com site displays menu links pointing to lang.example.com. Does anyone have any ideas on overcoming this? Maybe this solution can work if I just change some settings?